# Can I produce and sell a product that was patented more than 50 years ago?

Tags: us2982491

Can I produce and sell this patents product? It expired since it's in a patent from more than 50 years ago?  Pat. [US2892491](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2892491A/en?oq=US%202892491)

Answer (score 1):

You can't sell the patent but you could make and sell the product it describes.  This is the technology broadcast function of the US Patent and Trademark Office.

Be careful though because if it was manufactured they might be new patents referencing this one and a particular product may have a newer patent that would prevent you. This is called freedom to operate. –

Good luck;)

Comment: Be careful though because if it was manufactured they might be new patents referencing this one and a particular product may have a newer patent that would prevent you.  This is called freedom to operate.

Comment: You should add your comment to your answer.